# Multiple Categories for a single Article (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, tags, categories, article

Need help showing all the categories for a single article post.

***Here´s my database structure:***

**blog_posts** *table*

> **postID** *int, primary, auto increment.*
>
> **postTitle** *varchar*
>
> **postCont** *text*

**blog_categories** *table*

> **catID** *int, primary, auto increment.*
>
> **catName** *varchar*

**blog_posts_categories** *table*

> **postID** *int*
>
> **catID** *int*

---

***Database content:***

**blog_posts**

```
postID  |  postTitle  | postCont

  1          Post1       Cont1
  2          Post2       Cont2
  3          Post3       Cont3
  4          Post4       Cont4
  5          Post5       Cont5
```

**blog_categories**

```
catID   |   catName

  1          Music
  2          Games
  3        Technology
```

**blog_posts_categories**

```
postID  |  catID

  1          1
  1          2
  1          3
  2          2
  3          3
  4          1
  4          2
  5          2
  5          3
```

***here's the code i use to fetch data to the single post. an example post page URL would look like this: http://domain.com/viewpost.php?postID=1***

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); 

$stmt = $db->prepare("  SELECT * 
                        FROM blog_posts 
                        LEFT JOIN  blog_posts_categories ON blog_posts.postID=blog_posts_categories.postID 
                        INNER JOIN blog_categories ON blog_posts_categories.catID=blog_categories.catID 
                        WHERE blog_posts.postID = :postID");

$stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

//if post does not exists redirect user to homepage.
if($row['postID'] == ''){
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $row['postTitle'];?> | Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <h1>Single Post Page</h1>
        <hr />
        <p><a href="./">Home</a> | Categories: <?php echo ''.$row['catName'].''; ?></p>

        <div>
            <?php 
                echo '<h1>'.$row['postTitle'].'</h1>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['postCont'].'</p>'; 
            ?>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

for now this code just echo's 1 single Category name but i'd pretty much like it to show all the categories that are linked to that post nice in order. I just can't wrap my head around this don't know what to type I am pretty much still a beginner. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: A beginner who uses prepared statements. Well, you're already ahead of the curve, but don't use "SELECT *". Instead, name, and properly qualify, each column you actually want returned. As for grabbing all the returned rows, just use a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the SELECT! btw I followed allot of tutorials haha so i am pretty much stil a beginner!

i used this loop 

`<?php

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
  echo ''.$row['catName'].'';
}

?>`

but i keep getting 1 category name i just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

If your query return more than one line, you have to loop on the result of this query to achieve what you want.

An example can be :

`while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
  // Your stuff here
}`

If you use PDO, you can use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch`, and you will get an array instead of a single row (but you always need to loop).

Comment: i tried to do a while loop but i keep getting errors. can you help me out? 

edit: i tried the while loop like this: 

`<?php

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
  echo ''.$row['catName'].'';
}

?>`

but it still showed me 1 category.

Comment: In order to debug, you can use fetchAll like this :
`$result = $stmt->fetchAll(); var_dump($result);`
You will see how many lines you got with your query, and then you will be able to loop on `$result`  (it's an array).

Comment: It seems that your query returns only one line. Try with another postId, I see in your database some blogs have only one category (so you get only one result)

Answer (score 0):

That is already getting you the desired result, but in multiple lines. You are only fetching the first one. So you have only one category in the result.

One way to do what you want is this:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(catName) AS allCategories FROM ...
```

Then you only get one result line.
Echo it with `$row['allCategories']` instead of `$row['catName']`

Comment: To my mind, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT (or indeed CONCAT) is the solution.

Comment: @Strawberry What does that even mean?

Comment: Concatenation of any kind is best handled in the presentation layer. That way you maintain flexibility and scalabity, and preserve the 'intelligence' of the data.

Comment: That is your opinion! Not every project needs to be fine tuned to the last bit. This is a simple solution for the problem at hand!

Comment: Yeah, I said it was my opinion.

Comment: Because I look at it like this: Is the solution provided better or worse than what the OP has already? If I think it's worse, e.g. a single string of unformatted data stripped of its intelligence as opposed to a well-formed array which could (for instance) be easily parsed to a bit of json, then I opt for a downvote.

Comment: I totally disagree with Strawberry. GROUP_CONCAT solution provided by colburton should be the best answer provided that you need single row to come straight from DB. Repeated results of big texts can lead to a very large array fetched by DB. Sorr.